# Mouse pointer in Android-x86 inside Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, android, android-x86

Is it possible to see normal mouse operation in Android-x86 inside Oracle Virtual Box?

There are few apparent options for mouse, but neither work well

[image]

I can't find "Mouse Integration" option as was recommended in some old answers.

Comment: Machine->Disable Mouse integration. Or Host + I, to disable/enable it. I am using VBox 4.3.18.

Comment: I have the same question, but I don't virtualize it in a vm. It's installed on the disk.

Answer (score 13):

You can do the following:

1. Make sure the VM is powered off
2. Click on the VM name
3. Settings > System > Motherboard
4. Change Pointing Device to PS/2 Mouse

Comment: worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to see normal mouse operation... by turning off the Mouse Integration option as you alluded to. And:

"In VirtualBox 5.1.22, the Mouse Integration option is in the Input menu."

On Virtual Box for Mac, there is an Input menu when the virtual box is running:[image: Virtual Box menu]

On other platforms, I imagine it would be in the equivalent to a menu bar that you have in that platform. If you tell what platform you are running virtualbox on, perhaps I could help with that.

Comment: If you have comments about how moderation is handled, please check in on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/)

Comment: "If you tell what platform you are running virtualbox on, perhaps I could help with that." - The author's screenshot is the Windows version of VirtualBox

Comment: The screenshot was added after I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Machine->Disable Mouse integration or Host + I